# Informix cast varchar to byte

Tags: casting, byte, blob, informix, varchar

How to insert a varchar into byte(blob) column?

Consider i am having a table A with byte(blob) column 'name'.

INSERT into A (name) values('abc');
throwing error as **"617: A blob data type must be supplied within this context."**

Need to know whether there is any informix equivalent to below statement in oracle?
utl_raw.cast_to_raw('abc')

Answer (score 0):

There are two very different types — BYTE and BLOB — that you could be asking about. However, the formal message I see for error -617 is:

```
$ finderr -617
-617    A TEXT or BYTE data type must be supplied within this context.

This statement assigns a value that is not a simple large object to a BYTE or
TEXT column or assigns a BYTE or TEXT column to a column that is not a simple
large object. Neither action is supported. BYTE and TEXT values must be
assigned as whole units to columns of the same type. Check that the statement
specifies the columns that you intended.

$
```

This indicates that you are using the older 'classic blob' type — BYTE.  (There are text large objects too.  The older type is TEXT and the newer is CLOB, character large object.)

There isn't currently a built-in way to convert a VARCHAR string to a BYTE (or TEXT).  This has been a cause of pain since the BYTE and TEXT types were introduced circa 1990.  You don't give any indication of whether you are using Informix ESQL/C, or an ODBC driver, or a JDBC driver, or some other mechanism.  If you are using ESQL/C, you have to create a 'locator structure' (`loc_t` from `locator.h`) which uses a string representation of the blob — as opposed to various ways of storing the blob data in a file.  (I hope you're not on AIX because there are issues with a system-provided `loc_t` on AIX.  It's fairly easily worked around, but it's a nuisance you have to do so.)

I've not tried coding it in ODBC and don't know how to code it in JDBC so I can't pontificate on those.

I'm not so sure about the BLOB 'smart blob' type; there might be a function to convert from string to BLOB (or CLOB) type.